# AddSourceFilter behavior

Tags: winapi, audio, video, directshow, asf

The following code is good at rendering an MPG file without audio:

```
IBaseFilter *pRenderer;
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VideoRenderer, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRenderer)));
IFileSourceFilter *pSourceFilter;
IBaseFilter *pBaseFilter;
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AsyncReader, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSourceFilter));
pSourceFilter->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pBaseFilter));
pGraphBuilder->AddFilter(pRenderer, L"Renderer Filter");
pSourceFilter->Load(filename, NULL);
pGraphBuilder->AddFilter(pBaseFilter, L"File Source Filter");
```

But fails with an WMV file with audio. The failure happens at the following call, when I connect the only output of the video source with the only input of the video renderer.

```
pGraphBuilder->Connect(pOutPin[0], pInPin[0])
```

Which returns **-2147220969**. If I replace the code above with the following:

```
IBaseFilter *pRenderer;
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VideoRenderer, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRenderer));
IBaseFilter *pBaseFilter;
pGraphBuilder->AddSourceFilter(filename, L"Renderer Filter", &pBaseFilter);
pGraphBuilder->AddFilter(pRenderer, L"Renderer Filter");
```

then the MPG plays fine with:

```
pGraphBuilder->Connect(pOutPin[0], pInPin[0])
```

while the WMV results in the same error as above, but instead it plays **upside down** with:

```
pGraphBuilder->Connect(pOutPin[1], pInPin[0])
```

All of this means that the second coding style creates a source with two output pins, and probably audio is mapped to the first one. Or, maybe, an A/V splitter is inserted automatically by DirectShow.

- My understanding is that **AddSourceFilter** can create a splitter transparently. Is it correct?
- If I want to do it manually, which component should I use?
- Why the WMV video renders upside-down?

Answer (score 2):

> Which returns -2147220969

Which is [`0x80040217` `VFW_E_CANNOT_CONNECT` "No combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the connection."](http://alax.info/blog/1383)

which is the result of your manual adding `CLSID_AsyncReader`: Windows Media files are typically rendered through another source filter (use GraphEdit from Windows SDK to render a file and you will be able to inspect the topology).

> My understanding is that AddSourceFilter can create a splitter transparently. Is it correct?

Yes if splitter is compatible with Async Reader, which is not the case.

> If I want to do it manually, which component should I use?

Use GraphEdit to create topologies interactively and you will have an idea what to do on code.

> Why the WMV video renders upside-down?

Because of the topology. Most likely you have a weird combination of filters on the pipeline, including third party ones. Inspecting effective topology is the key to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use pGraphBuilder->AddSourceFilter() to add the source filter for a specific file. Don't assume that the File Source (Async) is the right source filter (for some formats, the source and demux are combined into a single filter).